# Strange behaviour when checking for NULL character in 'C'

Tags: c, pointers, null

To clarify a point I have written two small test programs given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                       

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *p = "ab";
    p++;
    p++;

    if (*p)
        printf("p is not NULL \n");
    else
        printf("ps is NULL \n");

    return 0;

 }
```

The program above initalizes the char pointer `p` to the string literal `ab`. I increment the pointer twice and then the if loop checks if `p` is pointing to a non-NULL character.This works fine and gives the following ouptut.

```
ps is NULL
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *p = '\0';                                                                                                                                                                      

    if (*p)
        printf("p is not NULL \n");
    else
        printf("ps is NULL \n");

    return 0;
}
```

The above program initializes the char pointer `p` to NULL character `\0`.If I compile and run the program I get segmentation fault.Can someone explain this?

The only difference in the two cases is the NULL character is at position `0` and position `2`.Otherwise the program looks identical to me.

Comment: `char *p = '\0'; ` sets the value of p to NULL.  It does *NOT* initialize p to point to NULL.  SUGGESTION: try `char *p = "\0"; ` or `char *p = "";`.  Try looking at the assembly output (gcc -S on Linux, or cl /Fa on Windows).

Comment: You are referencing a null pointer.

Comment: `NULL character is at position 0` : `char *p = ""; `

Comment: *p is a character pointer, and you initialize it with the character pointer "ab", and all is well. '\0' is not a character or a pointer, it's the integer 0. I suspect what you wanted is "".

Comment: @ssnobody: *Dereferencing*, not just referencing. Referencing a null pointer is harmless (as in `ptr = NULL;`).

Comment: Yup, definitely meant dereferencing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between a null *pointer* (`NULL`) and a null *character (`'\0'`).

```
char *p = "ab";
p++;
p++;
```

This correctly sets the pointer `p` to point to the null character at the end of the string `"ab"`.

```
char *p = '\0';
```

This sets `p` to be a null *pointer*. The use of `'\0'` as a null pointer constant is poor style, but legal (any constant integer expression with the value zero is a valid null pointer constant). The above is equivalent to the clearer:

```
char *p = NULL;
```

Any attempt to dereference `p` has undefined behavior, and will likely crash your program.

> The only difference in the two cases is the `NULL` character is at position 0 and position 2.

If you want a null character (not `NULL` character) at position 0, you can write:

```
char *p = "\0";
```

or, nearly equivalently:

```
char *p = "";
```

The empty string consists of just the terminating `'\0'` null character.

Comment: the "null character" isn't even called the null character. it's the NUL character (precisely because we need to avoid confusing the integer 0 and the null pointer).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Yes, it is. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.2.1p2: "                                                                                    A byte with all bits set to 0, called the *null character*, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string."

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Maybe you are thinking this since Windows has `NUL` while Linux/UNIX has `/dev/null` ? Further to Keith's reference of *null character* there is also a *null pointer* and we **do not** call it a *nul pointer*.

Comment: @localhost: The null character *is* often referred to as `NUL`. I believe it's the official (?) abbreviation in ASCII. Unicode calls it "NULL", but I try to avoid using that name for it when discussing C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Good point, even Wikipedia notes it (`NUL`) is referred as an abbreviation for `NULL` (whether official or not, I'm not sure either). In fact, it is likened to a *nop* in the article text. The article also says *null* is like *nop* in the fact that it *does nothing* (not entirely true in the sense that handling null-terminated strings still need to ensure the next value in said string is not a *null character*). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: @localhost no, I'm not confused. this really has **nothing** to do with the "eat'em all" files. why are you even talking about them?

Comment: @KeithThompson well, so it is. you're right. but I still prefer `NUL`.

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing a `char*` with an `int` value. If you turn on warnings, your compiler should warn you about this. Try:

```
char *p = "\0";
```

with double quotes.

Note that NUL (the character with code 0) and `NULL` (a pointer value that doesn't point to anything) are very different things.

Comment: I was about to post that too.

Comment: Actually `'\0'` is of type `int`, not `char` -- and it happens to be a valid null pointer constant (though using it that way is a bad idea).

Comment: This is wrong; the question is tagged `c`. In C, character literals are of type `int`. So, `'\0'` is an integral constant expression of value zero, hence it is a null pointer constant. If a compiler issues a diagnostic on this initialization, it is non-conforming.

Answer (score 3):

> The only difference in the two cases is the NULL character is at position 0 and position 2"

That is completely false. These two programs are actually very different.

The first program initializes `p` with an array of type `char [3]`. The array decays to pointer type, which makes `p` to point to string `"ab"` stored somewhere in memory. That string ends with a `\0` value at position `2`, which is exactly what you observed.

The second program initializes `p` with a character constant `\0`. That constant has type `int` and value `0`. This initialization initializes `p` with null-pointer value. It is equivalent to just doing

```
char *p = NULL;
```

The resultant `p` points nowhere. Inspecting `*p` causes undefined behavior.

If you want your second program to be similar to the first, you have to do it as

```
char *p = "\0";
```

or just

```
char *p = "";
```

Note the double quotes. That will make `p` to point to `\0` value in memory. But

```
char *p = '\0';
```

with single quotes is a completely different story, as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `'\0'` is an integer expression, so you have `char *p = 0;`. Therefore , `p` is a NULL pointer.

Also, note the distinction between a [`NULL`](http://c-faq.com/null/null1.html) pointer versus the [`NUL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character.

See [How do I get a null pointer in my programs?](http://c-faq.com/null/null2.html) :

> According to the language definition, an ``integral constant expression with the value 0'' in a pointer context is converted into a null pointer at compile time. That is, in an initialization, assignment, or comparison when one side is a variable or expression of pointer type, the compiler can tell that a constant 0 on the other side requests a null pointer, and generate the correctly-typed null pointer value. Therefore, the following fragments are perfectly legal:
>
> ```
> char *p = 0;
> if(p != 0)
> ```